# Can't add new object to the current state with use Effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I do have a state like this:

```
  const [serviceListData, setserviceListData] = React.useState({});
```

I want to add `Id` to my current state, so I implemented my code inside of `useEffect` hook.
it triggers every time `Insurance` and `count` changes.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (selectInsurance) {
      setserviceListData({
        ...serviceListData,
        ID: filtered.ID,
      });
    }
  }, [selectInsurance, count]);
```

but with this code, I only get my new state. previous state is getting removed. I console logged it and get this result:

```
Object {  }
EachInsurance.js:56
Object { ID: 189256 }
EachInsurance.js:56
Object { ID: 189256  }
EachInsurance.js:56
Object {  }
EachInsurance.js:56
Object {  }
EachInsurance.js:56
Object { ID: 189257 }
```

so at first stage my state is a empty object. then it gets the `ID` but as soon as I select another `Insurace`, the state gets erased and replaced with the new one.

what is the problem with my code. I thought it would spread old value (keeping it) and then adds new `ID`

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique can you show your example please?

Comment: I make a mistake in my old comment. SInce i can edit that comment, i have to delete it. You can check my answer how you can use state to store ids.

Comment: Yes this will happen, if `...serviceListData` contains a key `ID`.By this what you are doing is rewriting the value of `ID`

Comment: Does this filtered.ID need to be in depedency array of the useEffect

Answer (score 0):

When you try to add new value in serviceList, your key `ID` remains same. I'm assuming that you just want to store ids in state, then object is not appropriate to use here. Instead you can use array or if you want to store unique values then use `Set`.

**Array**

```
const [serviceListData, setServiceListData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =>{
  setServiceListData((prev)=> [...prev, filtered.ID]);

}, [selectInsurance, count])
```

**SET (If unique Ids)**

```
const [serviceListData, setServiceListData] = useState(new Set());

useEffect(() =>{
  setServiceListData((prev)=> new Set(prev).add(filtered.ID));
}, [selectInsurance, count])
```

If you want to store data related to that particular ID, then you can use object like this:

**Object**

```
const [serviceListData, setServiceListData] = useState({});

useEffect(() =>{
  setServiceListData((prev)=> Object.assign(prev, { [filtered.ID]: /*data*/ } ));
}, [selectInsurance, count])
```

Comment: I get an error with last two.  and with `Array` part. the first snippet. I get the same result. it replaces it.

Comment: You have to use one of the them according to your requirement. I don't know what is `filtered` but i looks like that some sort of state that you are using in your component. If that's so, add that to useEffect dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```js
const [serviceListData, setServiceListData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (selectInsurance) {
    setServiceListData([...serviceListData, {ID: filtered.ID}]);
  }
}, [selectInsurance, count]);
```